# How to run Firefox from script?

Tags: shell-script

I can run Firefox without a desktop environment by running the following commands in succession in a virtual console:

```
sudo pkill lightdm
X &>/dev/null &
DISPLAY=:0 compiz &>/dev/null &
DISPLAY=:0 firefox &>/dev/null &
```

I wanted to put them in a script and written the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo pkill lightdm
sudo pkill Xorg
sudo pkill compiz
sudo pkill firefox

X &>/dev/null &
DISPLAY=:0 compiz &>/dev/null &
DISPLAY=:0 firefox &>/dev/null &
```

but the script is not working.

What is the problem here?

Comment: `sudo` inside the script may be causing problems. What happens if you comment out the four lines with that command and run the script?

Comment: I says: 'X: user not authorized to run X server, aborting.'

Comment: So it's not an issue with Firefox, but running X as a regular user. Try removing all instances of `sudo` from the script and running it as is with `sudo myscript.sh` and seeing if that works.

Comment: @clk Yes, it works now. However not exactly as I expected. I don't get the command prompt back after running the script (which I have expected to get back). I have to make a `^c` to get it back. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @clk Also, I don't need to `sudo` to run X when I do it interactively from the virtual console. But the script required a `sudo`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: To the second question, I think you didn't need `sudo` to run X if you typed the commands as in your post, with another `sudo` command just before it. If you run X by itself, you'll probably need `sudo`.